How can I coefficients for a model of n linear differential equations in n unknowns
I have (a lot of) time series data, to which I wish to fit a system of n linear differential equations in n unknowns, where by "fit" I mean to find coefficients on the unknowns in a way that minimizes some loss function of the fitted model compared to historic data, such as the sum of the squared errors over my historic values or the negative of the  sum of the log(likelihoods). I know how to do this for a system of linear equations, or for a system of vector autoregressions, but not for a system of differential equations. I would also accept a solution of n linear difference equations, if that is more tractible.

Hi: If you include a small toy example, you may get more responses.
